# Search string using Pattern within long string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, search

I need to search for a pattern within a string.
For eg:

```
string big = "Hello there, I need information for ticket XYZ12345. I also submitted ticket ZYX54321. Please update.";
```

Now I need to extract/find/seek words based on the pattern `XXX00000` i.e. 3 ALPHA and than 5 numeric.

Is there any way to do this ?

Even extraction will be okay for me.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(big, "([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{5})"))
{
    if (m.Success)
    {
        m.Groups[1].Value // -- here is your match
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this. I wasn't expecting this much of response in such short time. :)

I've one more query, what if search pattern is like XXX00000 or XXX000000, i.e. 3 alphas and **5 or 6 numeric** ?

Comment: @GarthSebastian, "([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{5,6})"

Comment: I got one issue, if big string contains something like ABC1234567 then I get the result as ABC123456.
However, I need complete word based search. Any help ?

Comment: @GarthSebastian, please try `@"([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{5,6})\s"` (not tested)

Comment: Well, this \s is working however, if the string ends as ABC782362" i.e. no space at the end, then its not working. :(

Comment: I get it, I added space at the end, and then its working fine, thanks for your help :)

Comment: You need to replace \s with 'non-number' token. Please google it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
([XYZ]{3}[0-9]{5})
```

You can use [Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/) to test your expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple regular expression to match your following string

```
([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{5})
```

the full code will be:

```
string strRegex = @"([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{5})";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string strTargetString = @"Hello there, I need information for ticket XYZ12345. I also submitted ticket ZYX54321. Please update.";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a chatbot extension for the requests.

as for extracting the required information out of a sentence without any context
you can use regex for that.

you can use http://rubular.com/ to test it,
an example would be

```
...[0-9]
```

that would find XXX00000

hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex:

```
string ticketNumber = string.Empty;
var match = Regex.Match(myString,@"[A-Za-z]{3}\d{5}");

if(match.Success)
{
    ticketNumber = match.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex:

```
var str = "ABCD12345 ABC123456 ABC12345 XYZ98765";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(str, @"(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{5}(?![0-9])"))
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

The extra bits are the zero-width negative look-behind (`(?<![A-Z])`) and look-ahead (`(?![0-9])`) expressions to make sure you don't capture extra numbers or letters. The above example only catches the third and fourth parts, but not the first and second. A simple `[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{5}` catches *at least* the specified number of characters, *or more*.